# Breaking a journey after visiting a cemetery?

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, home-house

If one goes to a funeral and he wants to go home after, he needs to break his journey so as not to connect death and life or something along those lines, don't really understand it myself. (I've always been told to go to a shop before going home.) Is it Kaballah or Pshat Halacha?

Can one cite sources, preferably Sefardi ones including Rav Ovadia Yosef?

Comment: @DoubleAA I've heard this in the context of if you don't have water you can go to a non private building and wash there.  If the cemetery has a washing station, or if you're organized and leave it out in advance, or if you have a faucet and watering can outside, it's not relevant.